# How compare td text and change the backgroud color?

Tags: jquery

I want the background of `status` to be red if `qty` is less than `status`. Otherwise it should be green. Does anyone know how to do this in jQuery?

```js
$(function() {
  var rows = [];
  $('#customer_listing ').each(function() {
    var s1 = $("#customer_listing td:nth-child(5)").text();
    var ss = $("#customer_listing td:nth-child(4)").text();
    if (s1 <= ss) {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background', 'green');
    }
  });
});
```

This is the table:

```
id | name | qty  | status
-------------------------
1   | s1  | 0    | 1
2   | s2  | 4    | 3
```

Comment: Note for future reference, please always include the relevant HTML not an ASCII representation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to provide a function to `addClass()` which tests the values of the `qty` and `status` cells in each row, and returns the class to set on them based on those values. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#customer_listing tr td:nth-child(4)').addClass(function() {
    var status = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
    var qty = parseInt($(this).prev('td').text(), 10) || 0;
    return status > qty ? 'red' : 'green';
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: #0C0;
}
.red {
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="customer_listing">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>qty</th>
    <th>status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>s1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>s2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```